# Remove XML node if childnode's childnode contains specific value

Tags: python, xml, dom

I need to filter an XML file for certain values, if the node contains this value, the node should be removed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ogr:FeatureCollection
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://ogr.maptools.org/ TZwards.xsd"
 xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gml:boundedBy></gml:boundedBy>                   
    <gml:featureMember>
        <ogr:TZwards fid="F0">
            <ogr:Region_Nam>TARGET</ogr:Region_Nam>
            <ogr:District_N>Kondoa</ogr:District_N>
            <ogr:Ward_Name>Bumbuta</ogr:Ward_Name>
        </ogr:TZwards>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <ogr:TZwards fid="F1">
            <ogr:Region_Nam>REMOVE</ogr:Region_Nam>
            <ogr:District_N>Kondoa</ogr:District_N>
            <ogr:Ward_Name>Pahi</ogr:Ward_Name>
         </ogr:TZwards>
    </gml:featureMember>
</ogr:FeatureCollection>
```

The Python script should keep the `<gml:featureMember>` node if the `<ogr:Region_Nam>` contains `TARGET` and remove all other nodes.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml').getroot()

removeList = list()
for child in tree.iter('gml:featureMember'):
    if child.tag == 'ogr:TZwards':
        name = child.find('ogr:Region_Nam').text
        if (name == 'TARGET'):
            removeList.append(child)

for tag in removeList:
    parent = tree.find('ogr:TZwards')
    parent.remove(tag)

out = ET.ElementTree(tree)
out.write(outputfilepath)
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ogr:FeatureCollection>
    <gml:boundedBy></gml:boundedBy>                   
    <gml:featureMember>
        <ogr:TZwards fid="F0">
            <ogr:Region_Nam>TARGET</ogr:Region_Nam>
            <ogr:District_N>Kondoa</ogr:District_N>
            <ogr:Ward_Name>Bumbuta</ogr:Ward_Name>
        </ogr:TZwards>
    </gml:featureMember>
</ogr:FeatureCollection>
```

My output still contains all nodes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the namespaces in the python code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('/tmp/input.xml').getroot()
namespaces = {'gml': 'http://www.opengis.net/gml', 'ogr':'http://ogr.maptools.org/'}
for child in tree.findall('gml:featureMember', namespaces=namespaces):
    if len(child.find('ogr:TZwards', namespaces=namespaces)):
        name = child.find('ogr:TZwards', namespaces=namespaces).find('ogr:Region_Nam', namespaces=namespaces).text
        if name != 'TARGET':
            tree.remove(child)

out = ET.ElementTree(tree)
out.write("/tmp/out.xml")
```

Comment: Can you confirm it works? Because I still have the same amount of featureMembers if I run your solution. May it be a problem with namespaces?

Comment: One of your problems is that prefixes are not declared in your xml. So I remove them for my test. If you delete prefixes from your xml and the python code it works...

Comment: I deleted them because I thought they were obsolete for understanding... updated original post ^